# Easy Web interface development framework

Tags: java, web-development, javascript, django

So, I'm actually a DBA but a formerly Java/Python/Powerbuilder/C programmer.

In the past I joined a team as developer for a large government website written in Java + Struts 1.3 + Hibernate + Sencha EXT JS 4.

The question is... I'm working now in 2 projects as a freelancer. These are for 2 different customers, which one have different requisites.

One project, for example, is written in Python 3 + Django 1.6. The other, more complex, is written in Java + Struts 2 (this last is kind of legacy project, the programmer before me quit and left about 50% of the code to be written).

For these 2 projects I was thinking to use Sencha Ext JS 5. I am really a bad web designer, and do not have time - neither will - to start learning how to build "happy and beautiful pages". I'm good in programming and dealing with databases.

Before I start to search for a web developer to "prettify" my single html + js pages, is there any GUI framework that is easy to use and simple to code (more than Sencha EXT JS) that I could use in both Django and Java Web projects? I expect to use some Calendar widgets, tabpages and some Ajax requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to consider [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com). You will need some reading, but it's quite fast to have something good-looking. Trouble is, it will also look like a loot of other websites.

Regarding your needs, here is a [tab system](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) :

[image: tabs]

Here is a [calendar](https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar) (link by dimzak) :

[image]

Comment: The asker needs the software to assist with Calendar widgets, tabpages and Ajax, does Bootstrap cover these needs? I searched a bit for Bootstrap and found [this](https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar) for a Calendar widget

Comment: I'm adding this. Do you mind if I link the widget you found ?

Comment: sure that's why I added it in my comment :)

Comment: Yup, I liked bootstrap and don't mind if my site will looks like any other. BTW, the calendar widget I ask is for a input text masked as calendar with a button on the right side that when clicked pop-ups a mini calendar. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Though I recommend Bootstrap, there's also the option of jQuery and [jQueryUI](http://www.jqueryui.com) which has a wide variety of widgets including the calendar widget and is themeable directly from the site.